# Group records recursively in SQL based on minutes between them

Tags: sql-server, datetime, recursion, grouping

I have a data set similar to the sample below:

```
RecordId  RecordDateTime      AttributeA  AttributeB  Amount Value
--------- ------------------- ----------- ----------- ------ -------
1         2020-08-01 00:00:00 AttA01      AttB01      10.00   6510
2         2020-08-01 00:00:00 AttA01      AttB01      11.00   3620
3         2020-08-01 00:07:00 AttA01      AttB01      17.00  87430
4         2020-08-01 00:15:00 AttA01      AttB01      15.00   4140
5         2020-08-01 00:20:00 AttA02      AttB01      30.00   2350
6         2020-08-01 00:30:00 AttA01      AttB01      20.00  14560
7         2020-08-01 00:46:00 AttA01      AttB01      15.00   1370
8         2020-08-01 02:15:00 AttA01      AttB01      30.00   1380
9         2020-08-01 02:30:00 AttA01      AttB01       5.00   4490
10        2020-08-01 02:30:00 AttA01      AttB01       6.00  13100
```

I need to group all records where AttributeA and AttributeB are the same and where the next record's RecordDateTime is within 15 minutes from the current record's RecordDateTime.

The results should show the earliest date of the group, AttributeA and AttributeB, the sum of Amount and the earliest record in the group's value as the StartValue and the last record's value as the EndValue.

Example results:

```
RecordDateTime      AttributeA  AttributeB  Amount StartValue   EndValue
------------------- ----------- ----------- ------ ---------- ----------
2020-08-01 00:00:00 AttA01      AttB01      73.00        3620      14560
2020-08-01 00:20:00 AttA02      AttB01      30.00        2350       2350
2020-08-01 00:46:00 AttA01      AttB01      15.00        1370       1370
2020-08-01 02:15:00 AttA01      AttB01      41.00        1380      13100
```

I am struggling with the recursive grouping based on the time difference of 15min. I have tried a few things, including recursive CTE, but have not really made any progress worth showing. Is there an easy solution for the grouping?

**Edit:**
*Providing more detail as requested.* For the application there will always be a **start** and an **end** date that the user can dynamically select, which could span across multiple months starting on any day or time.

The data provided is manufactured data. In real life, AttributeA will be a person's name and AttributeB will be a location and the records are transactions.

Any series of transactions by the same person at the same location with a 0 to 15min (>= 0 and <= 15) delay between each transaction, must be grouped and summed and considered as one transaction. In other words, if a transactions is within 15 min from a previous transaction, it must be grouped with the previous transactions and any other transaction before that, that the previous transaction is grouped with.

At this point I do not care about any transactions that may have happened before or after the selected start and end date and times, even if they could form part of a series in the selected date range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a twist on an islands problem.

Given this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #x
(
  RecordId int, 
  RecordDateTime datetime, 
  AttributeA char(6), 
  AttributeB char(6), 
  Amount DECIMAL(12,2), 
  [Value] int
);

INSERT #x(RecordId, RecordDateTime, AttributeA, AttributeB, Amount, [Value])
VALUES
  (1,  '2020-08-01 00:00:00', 'AttA01', 'AttB01', 10.00,   6510),
  (2,  '2020-08-01 00:00:00', 'AttA01', 'AttB01', 11.00,   3620),
  (3,  '2020-08-01 00:07:00', 'AttA01', 'AttB01', 17.00,  87430),
  (4,  '2020-08-01 00:15:00', 'AttA01', 'AttB01', 15.00,   4140),
  (5,  '2020-08-01 00:20:00', 'AttA02', 'AttB01', 30.00,   2350),
  (6,  '2020-08-01 00:30:00', 'AttA01', 'AttB01', 20.00,  14560),
  (7,  '2020-08-01 00:46:00', 'AttA01', 'AttB01', 15.00,   1370),
  (8,  '2020-08-01 02:15:00', 'AttA01', 'AttB01', 30.00,   1380),
  (9,  '2020-08-01 02:30:00', 'AttA01', 'AttB01',  5.00,   4490),
  (10, '2020-08-01 02:30:00', 'AttA01', 'AttB01',  6.00,  13100);
```

I split this out with three CTEs:

- `x` determines which rows are "anchor" rows by finding any row with a timestamp that has elapsed more than 15 minutes than the previous row for the same A/B combination (or from the beginning of 2000 in the case of the first instance of any A/B combo). It assigns a column called `is_anchor` to easily identify these rows.
- `y` just applies a group by summing all of the `is_anchor` values from *all* previous rows for a given A/B combo, ordered by time. The effect here is that all the rows following an anchor that are not anchors are assigned the same group, because they all add `0` to the sum.
- `z` then, for each group, sums the `Amount` values and finds the *first* and *last* `Value`s. From `z` we select *only* the rows where `is_anchor = 1`.

The resulting query:

```
;WITH x(a,b,d,am,v,is_anchor) AS 
(
  SELECT AttributeA, AttributeB, RecordDateTime, Amount, [Value],
      CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, COALESCE(LAG(RecordDateTime, 1) 
      OVER 
      (
        PARTITION BY AttributeA, AttributeB ORDER BY RecordDateTime
      ), '20000101'), RecordDateTime) > 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  FROM #x
),
y AS 
(
  SELECT *, 
    grp = SUM(is_anchor) OVER 
          (PARTITION BY a,b ORDER BY d ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
  FROM x
),
z AS 
(
    SELECT d, a, b, is_anchor,
      Amount = SUM(am) OVER (PARTITION BY a,b,grp), 
      StartValue = FIRST_VALUE(v) OVER 
                   (PARTITION BY a,b,grp ORDER BY d, v),
      EndValue = FIRST_VALUE(v) OVER 
                   (PARTITION BY a,b,grp ORDER BY d DESC, v DESC)
    FROM y
)
SELECT RecordDateTime = d, AttributeA = a, AttributeB = b,
       Amount, StartValue, EndValue
FROM z
WHERE is_anchor = 1
ORDER BY d, a, b;
```

Results:

```
RecordDateTime           AttributeA  AttributeB  Amount  StartValue  EndValue
=======================  ==========  ==========  ======  ==========  ========
2020-08-01 00:00:00.000  AttA01      AttB01      73.00         3620     14560
2020-08-01 00:20:00.000  AttA02      AttB01      30.00         2350      2350
2020-08-01 00:46:00.000  AttA01      AttB01      15.00         1370      1370
2020-08-01 02:15:00.000  AttA01      AttB01      41.00         1380     13100
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b508239bda5fb4afdb057184f28c0eaa)

Comment: This solution works perfectly and kind of changed my approach to SQL problems in general. Just to clarify the rules on the start and end values, when there is a date tie for the StartValue, we need to select the smallest value and when there is a date tie for the EndValue we need to select the largest value.

Comment: @Corvex111 Updated the `FIRST_VALUE()` logic and added `EndValue` which I missed somehow the first time.